# Flutter resize image to fill available space

Tags: flutter

I would like to have this image fill the available space between the top element and the bottom element. Also I would like the bottom text to be always at the bottom.

This is how I implemented it right now:

```
Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Column(children: topWidgets),
        Container(
         color: Colors.red, 
         child: Column(children: [
             Image.asset("assets/empty_state/illustration_01.png", height: 200),
             Text("No matches so far")
           ]),
         )
     ]
)
```

I have tried to use the `fit` property of the `Image` without luck. If I don't use `height: 200` I wouldn't be able to see the bottom text because it would go out of the screen (at the bottom)

I don't know if having a `Column` wrapping text and image is a good approach but I think it is the best among the ones I tried so far.

[image]

Comment: Knowing what 'topWidgets' more or less is, could be usefull to help you

Answer (score 0):

```
Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height, //for max height
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,//for max width
  child: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        flex: 1, // flex is used to expand less/more the contained widget
          child: topWidgets),
      Expanded(
        flex: 3,
          child: Container( //for red background
        color: Colors.red,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              flex: 3, //increase to fill more space of picture
                child: FittedBox(
              fit: BoxFit.fill, // the picture will acquire all of the parent space. 
              child: Image.asset("assets/empty_state/illustration_01.png"),
            )),
            Expanded(
              flex: 1, //by default flex is 1. so don't do this and save a line
              child: Text("No matches so far"),)
          ],
        ),
      ))
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: nice! it works. The only thing is that `topWidgets` doesn't really fit in 1/4 of the screen, so I get an overflow. But if I use `flex: 1` for `topWidgets` and `flex: 2` for the `Container` then it works. Is there a way to let Flutter automatically figure this out?